# change cursor to pointer google-maps-react

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I am using [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react). By default, when I put the mouse on map, it shows a hand cursor. I would like to set a normal pointer when person hover on map, and only when start dragging, the cursor become again a hand cursor.

I was trying to set `draggableCursos` prop in many ways, but I didnt get what I wanted.

Thank You for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the current version (`2.0.2`) of `google-maps-react` package published in npm  does not support to specify a few properties including [`MapOptions.draggableCursor`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.draggableCursor) and [`MapOptions.draggingCursor`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.draggingCursor)  via Map component. In such a cases those properties could be specified via native map object. The following example demonstrates it

```
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMapReady = this.handleMapReady.bind(this);
  }

  handleMapReady(mapProps,map) {
    map.setOptions({
      draggableCursor: "default",
      draggingCursor: "pointer"
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="map-container">
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          className={"map"}
          zoom={this.props.zoom}
          initialCenter={this.props.center}
          onReady={this.handleMapReady}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rlyrje)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom className to the map and attach an event that will change the `pointer-events` CSS property on the map.